# How to disable reverse dns lookup in python webserver?

Tags: python, networking, dns

i have a simple python cgi server:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  ## This line enables CGI error reporting

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = server(server_address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

the server does a reverse dns lookup on every request for logging purposes onto the screen. there is no dns server available as i am running the server in a local network setting. so every reverse dns lookup leads to lookup timeout, delaying the server's response. how can i disable the dns lookup? i didn't find an answer in the python docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can subclass your own handler class, which won't do the DNS lookups. This follows from http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html#module-CGIHTTPServer which says [CGIHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html#CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler) is interface compatible with [BaseHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) and [BaseHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) has a method [address_string()](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.address_string).

```
class MyHandler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):

    # Disable logging DNS lookups
    def address_string(self):
        return str(self.client_address[0])

handler = MyHandler
```

Comment: Neat. I sometimes find it useful to quickly spin up a HTTP server using just "python -m SimpleHTTPServer".

Here's a one-liner that does the same thing but uses the above tip to disable the reverse DNS lookups.

python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer; SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.address_string = lambda self: str(self.client_address[0]); SimpleHTTPServer.test()"