# Where is the bottleneck in these 10 requests per second with Python Bottle + Javascript fetch?

Tags: javascript, python, performance, flask, bottle

I am sending 10 HTTP requests per second between Python Bottle server and a browser client with JS:

```
import bottle, time
app = bottle.Bottle()
@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return """<script>
var i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    let i2 = i;
    console.log("sending request", i2);
    fetch("/data")
        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then((arr) => {
            console.log("finished processing", i2);
        });
}, 100);
</script>"""
@bottle.route('/data')
def data():
    return "abcd"
bottle.run(port=80)
```

The result is rather poor:

```
sending request 1
sending request 2
sending request 3
sending request 4
finished processing 1
sending request 5
sending request 6
sending request 7
finished processing 2
sending request 8
sending request 9
sending request 10
finished processing 3
sending request 11
sending request 12
```

**Why does it fail to process 10 requests per second successfully (on an average i5 computer): is there a known bottleneck in my code?**

Where are the 100 ms lost per request, that prevent the program to keep a normal pace like:

```
sending request 1
finished processing 1
sending request 2
finished processing 2
sending request 3
finished processing 3
```

?

Notes:

- Tested with Flask instead of Bottle and the problem is similar
- Is there a simple way to get this working:

  - without having to either **monkey patch** the Python stdlib (with `from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()`),
  - and without using a much more complex setup with Gunicorn or similar (not easy at all on Windows)?

  ?

Comment: Did you look at: https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html. Using greenlets/gevent makes your code work fine for me.

Comment: Yes @MauriceMeyer, but I don't use `async` in my code. And also 20 per seconds is rather low, why does it start to fail at 10 or 20 requests per second - this is ridiculously low? PS: can you post the code you used with greenlets or gevent? I don't know how complex it will be to use it on Windows...

Comment: I don't use python / bottle, but from what I can gather the web server that comes as default is not very performant.. I think the main goal for bottle was to be a very minimalist web server.  But have you tried -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474993/bottle-loading-time-for-network-server-is-extremely-slow

Comment: Note that `setInterval` isn't perfectly accurate to begin with, so it'll drift over time, even if the server is working in parallel.

Comment: @ggorlen Which other solution would you use here? Recursive setTimeout? Feel free to post an answer (even if incomplete), I'm curious if we can do better than my example with pure Python + Bottle (or Flask).

Comment: @Basj It depends on your use case. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` have more or less the same performance characteristics. It's OK to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` when perfect timing isn't required, which is probably the case for HTTP requests. Just don't expect it to be perfect. This isn't enough info for an answer, just a note not to expect perfect accuracy from `setTimeout`/`Interval`. These are best-effort functions.

Comment: @Keith From Bottle's GitHub: "Bottle is a fast, simple and lightweight WSGI micro web-framework for Python." Just because it's minimalist doesn't mean it's slow (in fact, usually the opposite is true--more minimalism in the design means faster performance because there's left weight to lift).

Comment: @ggorlen I agree with this, and that's why I'm using Bottle. But here in my example, it's terribly bad to see that 10 or 20 requests per seconds is too much for the framework alone and that monkey patching the Python stdlib is necessary (see the `gevent` answer + the comments). Do you think there are solutions ?

Comment: @Basj I'm not remarking on that, I'm offering a side comment. Usually development servers don't have much paralellism and you'll need to use a real WSGI server like gunicorn. But I haven't looked into it nor do I have an answer offhand, sorry.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes I totally understand. But having to deploy a gunicorn for simple servers with only 10 requests per second is a bit complicated (espcially on Windows :)). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you (a) change the script to stop at 100 requests (b) how many backlogged requests are completed after the 100th requests (c) what browser are you using?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes (a) is easy with a check `if (i > 100) ...`  (b) yes we can easily see this in the console (c) Chrome and Firefox, it's similar

Comment: @basj how many requests are _finished_ after the 100th request is _sent_? Is it always around 3-5? Or some other number but almost same every time you test?

Comment: @SalmanA IIRC, half of them are finished when the 100th is sent

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely tied to flask+bottle? You can pretty easily get this working using a FastAPI server out of the box.

Nice thing with FastAPI is that this is then all single-threaded with asyncio support. No monkey patching or other weird behavior required by gevent. IMO that makes life A LOT easier.

Added in some timestamps to show that its sending roughly 10 requests per second.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index():
    return """<script>
var i = 0;
const start = Date.now();
setInterval(() => {
    const startOffset = Date.now() - start;
    i += 1;
    let i2 = i;
    console.log(`${startOffset}: sending request`, i2);
    fetch("/data")
        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then((arr) => {
            const duration = Date.now() - start - startOffset;
            console.log(`finished processing ${i2} in ${duration}ms`);
        });
}, 100);
</script>"""

@app.get("/data")
async def data():
    return "abcd"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

```
106: sending request 1
finished processing 1 in 22ms
208: sending request 2
finished processing 2 in 18ms
315: sending request 3
finished processing 3 in 20ms
420: sending request 4
finished processing 4 in 8ms
524: sending request 5
finished processing 5 in 27ms
624: sending request 6
finished processing 6 in 10ms
729: sending request 7
finished processing 7 in 39ms
831: sending request 8
finished processing 8 in 37ms
932: sending request 9
finished processing 9 in 12ms
1037: sending request 10
finished processing 10 in 7ms
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, using `gevent` makes your code run as expected. Just using gevent's monkey-patch capabilities no async-rewrite:

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()
import bottle

app = bottle.Bottle()


@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return """<script>
var i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    let i2 = i;
    console.log("sending request", i2);
    fetch("/data")
        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then((arr) => {
            console.log("finished processing", i2);
        });

}, 100);
</script>"""


@bottle.route('/data')
def data():
    return "abcd"


bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, server='gevent')
```

Browser console output:

```
sending request 158
(index):10 finished processing 158
(index):6 sending request 159
(index):10 finished processing 159
(index):6 sending request 160
(index):10 finished processing 160
(index):6 sending request 161
(index):10 finished processing 161
(index):6 sending request 162
(index):10 finished processing 162
(index):6 sending request 163
(index):10 finished processing 163
(index):6 sending request 164
(index):10 finished processing 164
(index):6 sending request 165
(index):10 finished processing 165
(index):6 sending request 166
```

**Note:**

You could create your own threaded WSGI server (so pure Python):

```
import bottle

from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, WSGIServer
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn


class ThreadingWSGIServer(ThreadingMixIn, WSGIServer):
    daemon_threads = True


class MyServer:

    def __init__(self, wsgi_app, listen='0.0.0.0', port=80):
        self.wsgi_app = wsgi_app
        self.listen = listen
        self.port = port
        self.server = make_server(self.listen, self.port, self.wsgi_app,
                                  ThreadingWSGIServer)

    def serve_forever(self):
        self.server.serve_forever()


app = bottle.Bottle()


@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return """<script>
var i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    let i2 = i;
    console.log("sending request", i2);
    fetch("/data")
        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then((arr) => {
            console.log("finished processing", i2);
        });

}, 100);
</script>"""


@bottle.route('/data')
def data():
    return "abcd"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wsgiapp = bottle.default_app()
    myWsgiServer = MyServer(wsgiapp)
    myWsgiServer.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Thanks! Using `gevent` only requires `from gevent import monkey` `monkey.patch_all()`, and that's all? Does it have other consequences on other code?

Comment: Yes, just call `monkey.patch_all()` before all other imports, to ensure all other libraries use the patched modules. For further information have a look at the [docs](https://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.monkey.html)

Comment: My Python program is fairly large and also interacts with other libraries (sometimes including hardware stuff) @MauriceMeyer, is there a way to use `gevent` without patching all the standard library (`monkey.patch_all()`)? This will probably have many consequences on the rest of my program, and I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: In case you do not monkey patch, there is no performance benefit. Maybe there is a threaded bottle solution somewhere, which I haven't checked/used.

Comment: Is there a middle solution between no patching at all, and `patch_all` @MauriceMeyer ? Also, which function of the stdlib is patched for example?

Comment: Those, are patched when using `patch_all`: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/081fa4e30af9ec70d9a43d9304ce7f3871727382/src/gevent/_patcher.py#L24

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean it's impossible to have 10 or 20 requests per second between Python Bottle (or Flask : the same, I just tried) and a 10-line JS code, without repatching half of the Python stdlib?  Arghh, this is terribly bad... (and I am a long-time pythonist ;))

Comment: @Basj: Edited, using pure Python threads.

Comment: Thank you @MauriceMeyer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work with the custom threaded version (and same problem also with `bottle.run(threaded=True)`: *sending request 1
sending request 2
finished processing 1
sending request 3
sending request 4
finished processing 2
sending request 5
finished processing 3
sending request 6
sending request 7*. Here it shows request #7 is fired and only #3 is processed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple explanation:

The browser and server need a finite amount of time to establish a HTTP connection. Bulk of the delay that you're observing is that setup time. Here is an example of Chrome requesting a plain text file from IIS server running locally:

[image: new connection]

If we eliminate the time needed to establish a new HTTP connection then it becomes:

[image: reusing existing connection]

In the above example, the browser and server were able to use `Connection: keep-alive`; the connection used to fetch *test-02.html* was ***reused*** to fetch *data.txt*.

Unfortunately Bottle Web Framework does not seem to support HTTP keep-alive. While this isn't necessarily bad, it creates another issue when the browser makes ***multiple requests to one origin***: only six requests could be executed in parallel, the remaining ones are queued. This explains the symptoms you mentioned.

You need to use another server. The alternative suggested in the other answer ***does*** support keep-alive. The first six requests will still take longer but remaining ones will not have the connection overhead. Your code has no speed issues. You could use [Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-explanation) to verify this.